# Можно ли вытащить лицензионный ключ Битрикс и использовать его на другом проекте?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Покупался ключ корп.портала, но возможности портала вообще никак не использовали. Ключ использовали 2 раза. Сейчас решили повесить сайт на редакцию "Старт", можно ли в этого сайта вытащить ключ корп.портала, использовать его на другом проекте, а на этот повесить "Старт"?

Comment: Ключи привязаны к типу продукта, в ключ вшито к какой лицензии он относится. Ключ от корпортала нельзя использовать для редакций "Управление сайтом". Создавать сайты на базе Битрикс24: Коробочная версия - можно, но это отдельное извращение поскольку придется сильно переделывать публичную часть. И из вашего сообщения ничерта вообще не понятно. Перечитайте сообщение и отредактируйте текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключ вытаскивать не надо, он в настройках продукта (marketplace-обновление платформы) опубликован в открытом виде. другое дело что вы не имеете право переносить активированный ранее ключ. но по опыту: это доступно через саппорт битрикса, обратитесь к ним, опишите ситуацию, предоставьте доступ и они вам помогут. покрайней мере у нас пару раз так и происходило.